# ASP.NET No postback on asp:ImageButton

Tags: asp.net, postback, imagebutton, autopostback

I have an ASP page with an asp:DropDownList (with AutoPostBack="true") so that when the user changes it, it reload the appropriate data.

Under that control i have a list of UserControls, that includes a tinymce editor (tied to an asp:TextBox) and an asp:ImageButton to save the data.

When clicking on the ImageButton, the applications send the postback data via ajax to the same page (__EVENTARGUMENT, __EVENTTARGET, etc...).  Why does it load that ajax page, and how do i prevent it?  I'm updating the value in the DB in the OnClick event handler on the ImageButton, so all I need to do, is get ride of that ajax call.

Any ideas?

Comment: you say it's making an Ajax request: are you using an UpdatePanel?

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btn" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/yourimage.jpg"
OnClientClick="return false;"  />
```

OR 
Solution 2

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btn" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/yourimage.jpg" 
OnClientClick="yourmethod(); return false;"  />
```

In addition (solution 2), your javascript method may be in this form

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function yourmethod() {
    __doPostBack (__EVENTTARGET,__EVENTARGUMENT); //for example __doPostBack ('idValue',3);
    }
</script>
```

in code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.IsPostBack) {
        string eventTarget = this.Request("__EVENTTARGET") == null ? string.Empty : this.Request("__EVENTTARGET");
        string eventArgument = this.Request("__EVENTARGUMENT") == null ? string.Empty : this.Request("__EVENTARGUMENT");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've not stated you're using an UpdatePanel but this is presumably how you've implemented  ajax calls. If so you need to add a trigger to exclude the imagebutton event from ajax:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"> 
<Triggers> 
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="ImageButton" />
</Triggers>
<ContentTemplate> </ContentTemplate> 
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```